# How to separate user roles in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How do I add user role authentication in firebase android app? From what I see, firebase only has email and password authentication. I want to develop an android app that has 2+ user roles. For example, if a normal member logs in, he will go to normal_memberActivity and if he's a premium member, he'll go to premium_memberActivity. How do I add roles in firebase? Wasn't able to find a similar problem like mine.

Normally, I would do it like this:

```
String role = intent.getStringExtra("role");

if (role.equals("admin")){
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new AdminHomeFragment()).commit();
}else{
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new NormalFragment()).commit();
}
```

Comment: You should save your users on the realtime Database. This way, you can create you custom User, with the role attribute. So everytime a user logs in, you can check his role on the database.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes is that different from Auth? If I'm going to use realtime database for my users, would it also be usuable for friends system?

Comment: Yes, it is the best way to create friends system. I hope you're familiar with databases. In case you've worked with SQL Databases, this might look a bit different for you (because firebase uses NoSQL JSON Database), but then you'll get used to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a roles node in the firebase database storing the user's uid and their role.

```
"roles" : {
    "uid1" : "normal",
    "uid2" : "premium",
    "uid3" : "normal",
}
```

Then you can get the role value after the user is successfully signed in

```
ref.child("roles").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String role = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        // check role and replace fragment
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: Will try it later! :) By the way, can you also give me a snippet on registering normal and premium user? Totally no idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Gian7 follow [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth), you can set the value to that "roles" node under `addOnCompleteListener`

Answer (score 6):

Firebase just launched support for role based access on any user via custom user claims on the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

You would define the premium access rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "premiumContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.role === 'premium'",
      ".write": "auth.token.role === 'premium'",
    }
  }
}
```

Set the user role with the Admin SDK:

```
// Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {role: 'premium'}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

This will propagate to the corresponding user's ID token claims.

To parse it from the token on the client, you need to base64 decode the ID token's payload.

You can upgrade/downgrade users as needed. They also provided a programmatic way to list all users if you have recurring scripts to change a users' access levels: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users