# How can I get user with role admin firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving users into firebase with the unique key generated by firebase push().getKey().now I want the keys which has role admin.
How can I achieve this?
Firebase Database

```
 -L8grpYQKUz1-jKxgwOI{
    email: "test@gmail.com",
    imageUrl:"https://test..",
    name:"test",
    role:"admin"
}
```

I want to get keys with the role admin.How can I write a firebse query?

Comment: Check this hope this useful to create to assign role of "Admin" :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666983/3974530

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("table_name").orderByChild("role").equalTo("admin");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have that users key stored in a shared preferences.so now I want to check if that key is same as the key in firebase.how can I do that?

Comment: @karankemble can u exaplain more