# firebase.auth().deleteUser - Error: "deleteUser is not a function"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have few authenticate users in the user list. And I want to remove one of them. Firebase documentation suggest me to use this code for remove any user.

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(id)
 .then(function() {
    console.log('Successfully deleted user');
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
});
```

So I use it in my project like this way. I use firebase.auth instead of admin.auth. so my code is like this.

```
firebase.auth().deleteUser(id)
   .then(function() {
      console.log('Successfully deleted user');
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Error deleting user:', error);
});
```

But it not working. Shows an error like this

```
deleteUser is not a function
```

Comment: Please [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800414/delete-a-specific-user-from-firebase)

Comment: still same problem. I use the code of this link . Now it says getUser is not a function. Is there any other way to remove an user from Firebase ?

Comment: Where do you use this code? Client or server side?

Answer (score 2):

The [`deleteUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthdeleteusers) function is defined for the [**Firebase Admin SDK**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). It appears that you are using the client-side [**JavaScript SDK**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). The Admin SDK needs to run on your web server, whereas the client-side JavaScript SDK would run in the browser.

For an overview on how to delete an individual user (or multiple users), see [**Delete a user**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

## Firebase Admin SDK

> The Admin SDK lets you interact with Firebase from privileged environments to perform actions like:
>
> - Read and write Realtime Database data with full admin privileges.
> - Programmatically send Firebase Cloud Messaging messages using a simple, alternative approach to the FCM server protocols.
> - Generate and verify Firebase auth tokens.
> - Access Google Cloud Platform resources like Cloud Storage buckets and Firestore databases associated with your Firebase projects.
> - Create your own simplified admin console to do things like look up user data or change a user's email address for authentication.
>
> If you are interested in using the Node.js SDK as a client for end-user access (for example, in a Node.js desktop or IoT application), as opposed to admin access from a privileged environment (like a server), you should instead follow the [instructions for setting up the client JavaScript SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Comment: I'm using directly the admin, and it does not work.

Comment: @SalahAdDin See docs for [Delete a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user)