# How does new Firebase Authentication billing work?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

*My app supports only login via Email/Password, Google, and Facebook using Firebase Authentication.*

*Inside the `Authentication -> Settings tab`, Firebase said to me `"Upgrade to Firebase Auth with Identity platform to access this feature."`*

*I upgraded successfully because I want to disable create a new account on the client side and disable delete account. These features are only what I want.*

*If you interested to know why I want to disable creating a new account on the client side? Please check [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73617894/why-there-is-no-rules-tab-inside-firebase-authentication) to know why.*

*Today I opened [Firebase Pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) and I found there are changes in Firebase Authentication, Firebase added 2 new rows in the last as you can see.*

[image]

*I was not charged in Phone verifications because I don't use this provider. I only charged for Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Storage.*

**Here are my questions:**

1. *`Identity Platform Pricing Monthly active users (excluding SAML/OIDC)` => If there were 83,000 daily active users (83,000 * 30 = 2,490,000), At the end of the month how much I'll be charged approximately?*
2. *`Monthly active users - SAML/OIDC` => As I said above my app supports only login via Email/Password, Google, and Facebook, Does that mean I'll not be charged about SAML and OIDC?*

*I hope everything is clear. Thank you.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have 83K monthly active users then you won't be charged for 50K users as it falls in the free tier. But you'll be charged for the next 33K users as per the pricing mentioned in [Google Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing):

[image]

From the documentation,

> Any account that has signed in within a given month is considered an active user. Inactive users are stored at no cost.

For the given example, you bill would be:

```
0.0055*33000 = $181.5 / month
```

> my app supports only login via Email/Password, Google, and Facebook, Does that mean I'll not be charged about SAML and OIDC?

Yes, if you are not using SAML/OIDC (Tier 2 providers) then you'll be charged based on Tier 1 pricing mentioned above only.

If you use any Tier 2 provider then you only have up to 50 free MAU and `$0.015 / MAU / month` thereafter.

Comment: If the user signed in 1,845 times during the same month, I'll be charged `10.14$` or `0.0055$`?

Comment: @TahaSami `0.0055$` they don't charge for how many times the user logs in. It's just cost per user per month as long as they are active. If they don't log in for a month then user will be considered inactive and won't be considered for billing that month.

Comment: It seems to be a big change which is not underlined clearly in the documentation. On an app with 10 millions users, there is a chance that 100% of all users open the app at least once in the month, which means it is equals to 10 millions monthly user so $55K cost...compared to the previous Firebase authentication sign if which was free...am i right?

Comment: @LearningPath I believe so, the pricing part is highlighted in detail when you are upgrading to GCIP from Firebase console.

Comment: The gap of costs between former and new solution is so important that it raises questions on understanding on MAUs counting : is there any technological reason brought by Identity platform which explains this raise of authentication costs?

Comment: @LearningPath, exactly my issue which I have been trying to understand. An app contains persistent logins so if the user logs in once, they won't initiate the login flow again(mostly). So does it mean that every time they just open the app(not login), they are considered as MAU and billed accordingly, right?

Comment: @AnujKaithwas 1MAU is a user logging in or just being active within that month. i.e. if I open your app or even relogin 100 times within same month, it's still 1 MAU.