# Understanding the difference between "Firebase Auth" and "Identity Platform"

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I have a confusion regarding the "Identity Platform" and "Firebase Auth". In my app I am only using email+password method to signup and signin, with Firebase Auth.

My confusion is regarding the pricing. As far as I know, "Firebase Auth" is free when we are using it with Email+Password. And I am not using Identity platform specific method as far as I know. I just register, login, get UID and do that kind of stuff.

I know Identity platform is not free. Understanding its connection with "Auth" is grey for me because seems they both have a connection.

So, when my active monthly users increase, Let's say it has become 100,000, and now what happens with the pricing for "Auth" ? is it free or will i get billed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is pretty well explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform).

Identity Platform is an upgrade from the base Firebase Auth product, and (long) list of features you get are listed there in the docs.

Unless you have gone through the upgrade process using the Firebase console, none of the features of Identity Platform available in your Firebase project, and neither are the costs that you read about.  From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform-upgrade):

> To upgrade your project to Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform, open the [Authentication Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) page of the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on [Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth#identity-platform):

> Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform is an optional upgrade that adds several new features to Firebase Authentication.

The list of additional features is mentioned there, so I won't duplicate it here.

##### On pricing

Firebase Authentication does not charge for users, but (if your project is on the paid plan) **may** charge for SMS messages that are sent for user's identifying with their phone number at the rate shown on the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) page.

Once you upgrade to Identity Platform, you are charged for both SMS messages sent and for the number of monthly active users over 50,000 at the rate shown in the [Google Cloud Identity platform pricing](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing) page.

Also see: [What is the difference between Identity Platform and Firebase Authentication with Identity Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73661376)

Comment: Thank you a lot! Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Saya lupa sandi Gmail/FB dan saya lupa no FB saya dan saya mau mengubah semua nya menjadi Gmail baru dan sandi baru /no hp baru

Comment: Not written in English