# Only authenticate with Google Auth Provider if user exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase to authenticate users in our app using `GoogleAuthProvider`. But I don't want a new user to sign in if they are not already an authenticated user.

If the **user exists** then sign them in and `console.log('user ' + user.email + ' does exist!');`.

However, if the **user does not exist**. Then do not allow authentication and `console.log('user ' + user.email + ' does not exist!')`

```
var googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const doSignInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider);

googleLogin = () => {
    auth
      .doSignInWithGoogle()
      .then(result => {
        var user = result.user;
        const userRef = db.collection('users').doc(user.uid);
        userRef.get().then(docSnapshot => {
          if (docSnapshot.exists) {
            userRef.onSnapshot(() => {
              console.log('user ' + user.email + ' does exist!');
            });
          } else {
            console.log('user ' + user.email + ' does not exist!');
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState(updateByPropertyName('error', error));
      });
  };
```

I thought referencing the user records in Firestore would be a simple approach to this. However, perhaps Firebase Auth already have a way to do this. I cannot find documentation or any example.

In the above code, nothing gets logged and the user is either created or logged in.

**How can I stop new users from signing up, whilst still allowing current users to sign in?**

Comment: Are you able to see if docSnapshot is not `undefined` in the handler for `userRef.get().then`?

Comment: Is this similar to your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357554/how-to-disable-signup-in-firebase-3-x

Comment: Hey @Josh. Unfortunately not. Any attempt at `logging` any part of the above code is ignored. It is as if the proceeding `promise` after `doSignInWithGoogle` are ignored. I do know based on use in other scenario's, the `userRef.get().then` will return results.

Comment: Thanks @MaximillianLaumeister. Yes, similar. Yet, I only want to restrict signup via `doSignInWithGoogle` in a single component, not the entire app. I handle signups via a different on-boarding journey.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you really want to use `signInWithPopup` method, you have this option,
but it's not the best way. when you are signing in with google, `signInWithPopup` method returns a promise. you can access the `isNewUser` property in `additionalUserInfo` from resulting object. then delete the user you just created.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(
     function (result) {
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          var user = result.user;

          //this is what you need
          var isNewUser = result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser;
          if (isNewUser) {
               //delete the created user
               result.user.delete();
          } else {
               // your sign in flow
               console.log('user ' + user.email + ' does exist!');
          }
     }).catch(function (error) {
     // Handle Errors here.

});
```

This is the easy way but deleting after creating is not the best practice. There is another option,

you can use, `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` method for this. according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential),

> `auth/user-not-found` will be
> Thrown if signing in with a credential from
> `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential` and there is no user
> corresponding to the given email.

```
function googleSignInWithCredentials(id_token) {
     // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
     var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);

     // Sign in with credential from the Google user.

     firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
          .then(function (userCredential) {
               //sign in
               console.log(userCredential.additionalUserInfo.username);
          }).catch(function (error) {
               // Handle Errors here.
               var errorCode = error.code;
               if (errorCode === 'auth/user-not-found') {
                    //handle this
               } else {
                    console.error(error);
               }
          });
}
```

[here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/google-credentials.html) is an example from firebase github repo.

Comment: Thank you - The second option with some tweaking worked perfectly to the scenario.

Comment: awesome..! glad I could help. :)

Comment: Is there a similar method to `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` for Android?

Answer (score 2):

with `Firebase` security rules, can only check if keys exist - therefore searching in the users table is not an option:

```
"emails": {
    "example1@gmail.com": true,
    "example2@gmail.com": true
}
```

and then one can check with security rules, if the `auth.token.email` exists **as a key**:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": "root.child('emails').child(auth.token.email).exists(),
        ".write": false,
    }
}
```

in the client, this should throw an `"The read failed: Permission denied error"` error then, to be handled accordingly. hooking into the Firebase sign-up isn't possible - but while they cannot log-in, this has the same effort (except that on has to clean up the user-database from time to time); eg. with a Cloud Function, which deletes users, which do not have their email as key in the `emails` "table".

in `Firestore` security rules, one can check with:

- `request.auth.token.email` & `request.auth.token.email_verified`

for example, with a collection called `emails` and a collection called `content`:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function userMatchesId(userId) {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
    }
    function readAllowed(email) {
        return if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/emails/$(request.auth.token.email)).data != null
    }

    match /users/{userId} {
        allow get: if userMatchesId(userId)
    }
    match /content {
        allow get: if readAllowed(request.auth.token.email)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Martin. I had looked at this scenario but it would then take hold over the entire app. Yet, I am only looking to restrict the sign-in to current users on the sign-in page, whilst sign-up will be allowed on the sign-up page. Is that possible when setting the security rules? Can I apply these rules to, let's say, just the URL or pathname?

Comment: Is it possible to check if keys exist as above. Therefore `.doSignInWithGoogle().then(result => { //check if key exists`?

Comment: @Darren with an example structure, alike in my first example... I could show how to structure it. of course this should be configured to the scope of the content available after the successful login.

Comment: Thank you, that would be great. I am just reading up on your answer in the Firebase Docs.

Answer (score 1):

The object you receive from firebase after login has `additionalUserInfo` where you have the property `isNewUser`.

You can find the reference here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.html#.AdditionalUserInfo