# How to make admin approve new user firebase auth flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I Have a Project Manager App With 3 roles (Admin - Engineer - technicals) I want to make
**admin approve new Users before they can authenticate to firebase** by sending OTP (One-time password) to signup.
So that no one can create a new Account on firestore without admin permission.
I'm using flutter 2.2 And Firebase Email/Password Authentication.

Comment: You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which explains how to create an Admin module for managing Firebase users access and roles.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is to have preferences associated to every user in a separate collection. You can have your login function check if userId.isApproved is true and if it is, you continue. Otherwise, you'd log them out and redirect them to a page saying "This user in not approved"

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what you're trying to do is set up Role Based Access Control (RBAC).

Here is a solution that might fit your use case:
You can follow the instructions here: [How to disable Signup in Firebase 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357554/how-to-disable-signup-in-firebase-3-x/68829085#68829085) to disable registration and allow only the admin-sdk to create accounts. Once users apply (perhaps by creating a new Firestore document), admins can view their application and use the admin sdk to create a new account and notify the user.

The more common solution for an RBAC system is to control access with custom claims. Here's how that could work:

**1.** An onCreate cloud function trigger notifies your admins of a potential new user (eg add a document to a Firestore collection).

**2.** The admins then view and assign those users to either the Admin, Engineer, or Tech role/custom claim using the admin sdk.

**3.** You use these custom claims throughout your Firebase services (Firestore, RTDB, Storage, Functions) to control their access across your project.

**4.** If the admins wish to deny the user, they can use the admin sdk to remove the account.