# authentication with google in firebase alone users created Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, angular13

"How can I do so that the authentication with google by firebase is only for already created users?  Not create user"

I need the already registered user to log in with google. do not create a new user.

that google verify in firebase that the user exists and if it exists, start the session

Comment: Hi, can you please update your question to be better described? I have no idea what you are trying to do. You want to disable possibility to register to your app?

Comment: yes, that with google only the user that is created starts the session, not create a new one.

Comment: This isn't built into Firebase Authentication at the moment, but *is* an option in Google Cloud Identity - its paid cousin. Once you upgrade your project to that, you can disable account creation in its console. See Dharmaraj's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68829085/209103