# Firebase Auth - Disable Register

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

Can we disable register without upgrading to Identity Platform. It looks quite expensive.

If i understand correctly;
We cannot disable new user register without Identity Platform upgrade and it costs 275 USD for +100k unique login monthly.

And advise?

Comment: See this [How to disable Signup in Firebase 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357554/how-to-disable-signup-in-firebase-3-x).